# Check land or water in google map

Tags: android, google-maps

I am generating random latitude and longitude. But unable to find land or water for random lat and longitude. Checked with google API, I am not finding and I searched in google. But I cannot find solution, please help me. I used this source (https://onwater.io/users/sign_up )url. It gives only 15 request per minute. I need 50 lat and long to check whether it is land or water.

Comment: Did you checked  Google Reverse Geocoding.

Comment: @RissmonSuresh no,it will return land or water??if it is pease,share url,it will be helpful for me

Comment: @RajaSankar ckeck this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9644812/4247543

Comment: Looks like Geocoding API doesn't have this feature at the moment, there is a feature request you might be interested in: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35822507

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For today easiest way to do this is to use Google [Static Map API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/?hl=en) and [Styled Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/styling): you can create request for just one pixel map (size=1x1) for your Lat/Lon coords with hidden all features except `water` and set `water` color to e.g. pure blue (`0x0000FF`). Something like that

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?&center={YOUR_LAT},{YOUR_LON}&zoom={YOUR_ZOOM}&size=1x1&style=feature:all|visibility:off&style=feature:water|visibility:on&style=feature:water|color:0x0000FF&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

Then download it (like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16141970/6950238) answer of [Vivek Khandelwal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1142807/vivek-khandelwal)):

> ```
> ...
>
> public static Bitmap getGoogleMapThumbnail(double lati, double longi) {
>     String URL = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + lati + "," + longi + "&zoom=15&size=200x200&sensor=false";
>     Bitmap bmp = null;
>     bmp = getBitmapFromURL(URL);
>     return bmp;
> }
>
> public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
>     try {
>         URL url = new URL(src);
>         HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
>         connection.setDoInput(true);
>         connection.connect();
>         InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
>         Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
>         return myBitmap;
>     }
>     catch (IOException e) {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>         return null;
>     }
> }
> ...
> ```

and test color of one pixel like in [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7807442/6950238) answer of [Raz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/590221/raz):

> ```
> ...
> int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);
> if (pixel == Color.BLUE) {
>    // water!
> }
> ...
> ```

if it blue (`0x0000FF`) - there is water on your Lat/Lon coordinates.

NB! You should set appropriate zoom level and remember that is no map tiles for all zoom levels for entire Earth. Also some water/earth can be missed on map. So, that is not 100% right solution, but hope it helps.