# Detect if user is indoor or outdoor using mobile sensors

Tags: android, android-sensors, sensormanager

I am trying to detect whether user is `indoor` or `outdoor` using Acceleromter, magnetic field and light sensor. I am using the following method:

**Registering the Sensor Manager**

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        sensorManager.registerListener(this,
                sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);

        sensorManager.registerListener(this,
                sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);

        sensorManager.registerListener(this,
                sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
    }
```

**Sensor Listener and Calcualtions for different sensor types**

```
override fun onSensorChanged(event: SensorEvent) {
        val values = event.values
        when (event.sensor.type) {
            Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD -> {
                mag_val = Math.sqrt(values[0] * values[0] + values[1] * values[1] + (values[2] * values[2]).toDouble())
            }
            Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT -> {
                light_val = values[0].toDouble()
            }
            Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER -> {
                acc_val = Math.sqrt(values[0] * values[0] + values[1] * values[1] + (values[2] * values[2]).toDouble()) / 10
            }
        }
    }
```

Which combination of values should I consider to decide that user is Indoor or Outdoor? Currently, searching online I used the following values but it is showing wrong decisions:

```
fun isOutDoor(): Boolean {
        if (light_val > 900) {
            return true
        } else {
            if (mag_val > 80) {
                if (acc_val > 1.3) {
//                    "OUTDOOR_NIGHT"
                    return true
                } else {
//                    "OUTDOOR_BUS"
                    return true
                }
            } else {
//                "INDOOR"
                return false
            }
        }
    }
```

Please guide which combination of values should be for Indoor buildings and outside?

Comment: It is hard to say what values are the best for some case. It would be better for you to make an app and print some values on a screen when you are in some scenarios...

Answer (score 0):

You need do gather some dataset from all of the possible sensors (seems barometer, date-time etc. are also useful) and use Machine Learning to create more accurate classification model (take a look at [this](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-02011454/document), [that](https://lembergsolutions.com/blog/motion-gesture-detection-using-tensorflow-android) or [that](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/325686162_Smartphone_sensor-based_activity_recognition_by_using_machine_learning_and_deep_learning_algorithms) as examples).

Also, you can try workaround like that:

1. Use GPS (or other location provider) to get location coordinates;
2. Use [Styled Static Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/styling) and set all outdoor places to same solid color e.g. pure red (0xFF0000) get one pixel map bitmap for location from p.1 and check it color (like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47990665/6950238) answer). If it pure red (0xFF0000) - user is highly likely outdoor.

Of course you can use combinations of workaround with yours "decision tree" approach.